# Launcher Icon shows up on emulator, but not on phone

Tags: android

As mentioned in the title, my launcher icon is showing up fine on the emulator, but the default icon was shown on my phone.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ytz.bc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0a" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProjectBriefcaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you have replaced the default icon with your icon only in one of the drawable folders, and coincidentally the emulator is using the folder, while your device is using one of the other folders. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) link for icon design guidelines, and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size) one for the recommended size.

Comment: I used http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html to create the icon, and after fiddling around it finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you post what's there in all your drawable folders?

You might have done this thing: replaced the ic_launcher.png file in drawable-mdpi folder with another image(your launcher icon) and named it ic_launcher.png .

You actually do not need to rename the file icon file you out in the drawable folder, but you need to change the android manifest to tell the application which file to use as the launcher icon.

Suppose if i put launcher_icon.png in the drawable-mdpi folder, and i want that to be my launcher icon, i will change the manifest to this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

I changed the tag

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

to

`android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"`

paste your launcher image and do the change according to the file name of that image...

Answer (score 0):

If you have placed your icons correctly, still you don't see the icon change then, go to `Project`->`Clean...`.

In `res` folder inside `bin` you will find all your resouce items. You can check before cleaning the project and you will find that you have the old `ic_launcher` file. If you clean the project, these folders will be deleted. When you run your application again a new set of files will be copied and your application icon will be changed.

Hope this helps.

**Note:** This will work only when you have replaced the icons in all the folders still you are getting the old icon.