# App icon showing only on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, appicon

I have placed my app's icon.png image in the respective mipmap folders in my project but when i or any of my testers install the app on a physical device, the icon is replaced by android studio's default icon. However, it works fine on emulators.I haven't found a way to fix this for a while now, anybody got any ideas?

Comment: see here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176198/launcher-icon-shows-up-on-emulator-but-not-on-phone
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon.png"
```

also add this in manifest

Comment: This worked for me. I don't understand why, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do this via menu

```
File -> New -> Image Asset
```

It will produce different size of icon for different device size